# Spring boot - search function

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I need to implement the search function with spring boot. In front-end i have the column NAME which is composed from(firstname and lastname). My problem is: for example if i have NAME:ION POPESCU and i search for 'ION P' in my database it looks for firstname and lastname separately and doesn't find anything. 
There is a way to concatenate this two columns in the back-end?

I've tried to use @Query annotation with something like this:
 @`Query("SELECT CONCAT ('firstname', 'lastname') AS NAME FROM User e")`

but didn't worked.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You receive this String : `NAME=firstname + lastname` you can separate this String in 2 strings and use a `findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname,String lastname)`